# BackgroundSubtractorCNT misses in opencv 4.1.0

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to integrate Background Subtraction into my OpenCV Software which is going to be integrated onto a low specced embedded system. For that reason, I want to use the BackgroundSubtractorCNT class provided by OpenCV since it runs more smoothly on limited hardware. However, my OpenCV installation does not seem to have the necessary files and the code to do so.

According to the official documentation on the OpenCV Website (I am using version 4.1.0 and also looked for the exact documentation for this version), I need to include <opencv2/bgsegm.hpp> in order to use this class. This file is nowhere to be found, neither in my self-extracted build of OpenCV 4.1.0 nor in my version installed with vcpkg. The file <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp> only has headers for the BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 and BackgroundSubtractorKNN classes.

Am I missing something completely? Have the other Background Subtractor classes become deprecated? I can't find any information on this whatsoever, so I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It works after I installed the opencv-contrib packages